# Multiple Users Updating Excel Sheet - Maybe Disconnected ADO Recordset?

Tags: vba, excel

I have the below excel sheet that is set as shared and is being access by multiple users within the team:

[Sheet http://im47.gulfup.com/xQTWqT.png](http://im47.gulfup.com/xQTWqT.png)

As the sheet is being updated with new records very often, I have set the below sharing options and that the sheet is being saved and the other users changes are being updated every five minutes (the minimum that you can set):

[Options http://im47.gulfup.com/SBX4jf.png](http://im47.gulfup.com/SBX4jf.png)

The problem happens when 2 users try to update the database at the same time within the 5 minutes, then excel will prompt them that this cell already contains data and will offer to resolve the changes.

Is there any way to avoid this happening.

I have searched and come across Disconnected ADO Recordset, but I am not very clear on how they could aid in my scenario.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You have vba tagged in your question but I am not understanding how this pertains to vba.

Comment: @bp_ You wouldn't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind I figured it out:

Create a user entry form in one workbook, and create another workbook for the storage of the data (lets call it Book1).

Next this is the code:

```
    Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

'  Add the ActiveX Object Library
'  Tools ---> References ---> Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.5 Library

    Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
    With cn
        .Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
        .ConnectionString = "Data Source=C:\Users\Name\Downloads\Book1.xls;" & _
    "Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;"
        .Open
    End With

    strSQL = "INSERT INTO [Sheet1$](Name, Age, Nationality, Amount) values('" & UserForm1.TextBox1.Value & "','" & UserForm1.TextBox2.Value & "','" & UserForm1.TextBox3.Value & "','" & UserForm1.TextBox4.Value & "')"
    cn.Execute strSQL

    End Sub
```